# How to create a checkmark on a uitableviewcell with a unbutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm not a beginner in Objective-C but I am fairly novice to UITableViewCell.

I'm trying to give the user the ability to create a checkmark on the TableViewCell by pressing on a button. Here is the code that I came up with,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cellx = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 5, 40, 40)];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [button setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [button setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellx addSubview:button];
    [cellx setIndentationLevel:1];
    [cellx setIndentationWidth:45];

    if (button.touchInside == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
        cellx.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    return cellx;
}
```

And that code doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called when refreshing/rendering a cell. You need to capture your button press, find out what cell it was on, set a property on that cell that notes it should be checked, and then refresh the cell.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPaths;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (NSMutableArray *)selectedIndexPaths {
  if (!_selectedIndexPaths) {
    _selectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
  }
  return _selectedIndexPaths;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  } else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }

  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  } else {
    [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A strategy that works better is:

- create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and build its interface
  in IB so the button is there when it loads
- keep an array of objects
  where each object represents what you want to show in one cell
- when the button is tapped, tell your controller to update the matching array object to say it
  should be checked
- tell your table view to reload data, either entirely or for changed index paths
- in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just update the button to be
  checked or not depending on the matching array item.